# A question pertaining to using a hyphen

Tags: hyphens

Is there a need to put a hyphen between the words super and happy in the sentence given below? If there is no need to put a hyphen then what could be the explanation?

He is super-happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a hyphen there. Hyphens can be used when two adjectives are combined to form a single adjectival unit.

You might use a hyphen if the phrase *super-happy* modified a noun:

> After he got his raise, Bob was a super-happy camper.

However, in your brief snippet, I think a hyphen is unnecessary and distracting.

Punctuation usage is often a stylistic choice, and guidance can vary. However, I've found the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/) to be a good resource (and you probably should have checked a website like that one before asking your question here). It plainly says:

> **Use a hyphen to join two or more words serving as a single adjective before a noun:**
>   *a one-way street
>
>   chocolate-covered peanuts
>
>   well-known author*
>
> **However, when compound modifiers come after a noun, they are not hyphenated:**
>   *The peanuts were chocolate covered.
>
>   The author was well known.*